# Using .show() in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a class on a div ($('#cover-image-item')) that has:

```
display: none;
```

In my js I have:

```
$('#cover-image-item').css( "display", "block");
$('#cover-image-item').show();
```

The div is not shown when the js code is ran, where am I going wrong?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: This code should work, can you create an example to show your issue?

Comment: `.show()` will update the `display` property for you, there is no need to change it first.

Comment: Have removed the display block bit. Still does not work.

Comment: @panthro You'll need to show more code then. The code you posted here should work.

Comment: Show what more code? The rest is irrelevant,

Comment: your html show it, show what cover-image-item is

Comment: Make sure you have something in your div and that something is displaying. Also add more code and dont expect the magic answer

Comment: @panthro Something obviously isn't irrelevant if this isn't working, because it should. Try recreating the issue in a http://jsfiddle.net/.

Answer (score 3):

If `cover-image-item` is indeed a class and not an ID, you need to use `$('.cover-image-item')` not `$('#cover-image-item')`.

As others have mentioned, there's no need to update the `display` value, as that gets updated by `show()`

Answer (score 2):

The [# means "id" attribute](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), not class.  Made sure your div is this:

`<div id="cover-image-item" />`

If it is this...

`<div class="cover-image-item" />`

...change your jQuery selector to [class](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

`$('.cover-image-item').show();`

Comment: Can you post your HTML for the "cover-image-item" `<div>`?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to remove the class attached to the div.

$('#cover-image-item').removeClass('hidden');

Comment: Can you show your relevant markup for the `<div>` in your question so that this has better context?

Answer (score 0):

Don't write .css("display","block")

Answer (score -1):

remove the `.css("display, "block");`

Comment: if it is a class, you must use $('.cover-image-item').show(); not $('#cover-image-item').show();

Answer (score -2):

The `.css( "display", "block");` is unnecessary and possibly causes your problem.

Comment: I agree that it is unneccessary but I don't see how it can cause it to NOT show

Comment: @Huangism if he is using the display otherwhise to position his element (inline-block for example) setting it to block can break his layout and possibly cause it to not show. It's safer to just use `show()` as it will revert the display to it's previous value.

Comment: Layout might break but it will still show up somewhere. It's hard to say without seeing some more markup

Comment: Indeed. It's more likely his problem is caused by other conflicting code.

Comment: not from me but carefully reading his question, he says class when he targeted id.

Comment: panthro's own answer mostly confirms an alternate implication: that the `<div>` had both the `id` and an additional `class` on it, where the `id` was being used in the jQuery code, while the `class` was used for the `display: none;` CSS rule. This was not clear in the question.

Comment: Tbh none of us could have figured out the correct answer with the limited information he posted. My answer was a guess but also a possible cause, I don't see why it needs 3 downvotes.